# Model derivative fetch properties for object id(s)

Tags: autodesk-model-derivative

We have some big models where we need to read properties via the model derivative api. Reading all properties leads to an out of memory of the heap. We need to check the properties of each object for a custom prop set in a cad program like revit or navisworks.

So we are exploring to fetch properties for an object, explained here:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/new-objectid-query-parameter-model-derivative-properties-api

But after reading the metadata for the guid, we have like 50k of objectids or more. Thats too much to fetch the properties separately per object.

Is there a possibility to:
 - fetch properties for multiple object id's?
 - Fetch the properties for an object id and all his children?

Or is there another recommendation on how to handle such big models where the response when reading all the properties is too big (and we don't know up front which objectIds to read properties from)?

kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I completely understood your question and as I know you working with .nwm format which is basically includes all the files from project (this is the reason for such amount objects in metadata)

For such case you can use middle-ware server with custom helpers methods, please take a look on this repo from Cyrille Fauvel,

https://github.com/cyrillef/propertyServer

It can help you working with multiple id, with range of id's, some methods you can take as base for your own.

Also, as far as I understood you getting property programatically so maybe you can some how use 'name' field in metadata object which is also can be unique as 'guid'.

Comment: Hi,

Thx for the response. Ill look into the property server. 

But can you elaborate a little more on the 'name' field in the metadata object?

Comment: Thomas this is only a quick guess but theoretically you can try name one of your "object". I don't know with which application you work before creating sample with navisworks, (if you will specify this I can speak with derivative team about it more detailed). And then after you named your detail or plan or whatever you may try to filter array of your objects by this particular name.I also ask this question to dev. team so I will wait how they answered